# узнать время аудио

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно как-то узнать общее время аудио-файла и текущее время если файл воспроизводиться.

Ну как в плеерах, думаю понятно описал.

---

Допустим воспроизведение происходит через такой код

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'click.mp3';
audio.autoplay = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'click.mp3';
audio.autoplay = true;

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('общее время ' + audio.duration + ' секунд');
});

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('прошло ' + audio.currentTime + ' секунд');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn1">Общее время в секундах</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Текущее время(сколько прошло)</button>
```

Для проверки загрузки данных файла можно использовать `onloadedmetadata`, пример:

```
audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  console.log(audio.duration);
  console.log(audio.currentTime);
};
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [currentTime](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp)
- [duration](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp)
- [onloadedmetadata](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onloadedmetadata.asp)